# How to make the limit split for when finding total area with integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I'm pretty confused to how to make the split (before computing FTC) for definite integral problems where you have to find total area

let's say:

$$\int _2^3\left|x^2-2x-3\right|dx$$

I was trying to factor and get

$$\left(x+1\right)\left(x-3\right)$$

from there I try to get a split of

$$\left.x^2-2x-3\right.\ ,\  x < -1$$
$$\left.-(x^2-2x-3)\right.\ ,\ -1<x\le 3$$
$$\left.x^2-2x-3\right.\ ,\  x \ge  3$$

but according to [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint_%7B2%7D%5E%7B3%7D%20%5Cleft%7C%5Cleft(x%5E%7B2%7D-2x-3%5Cright)%5Cright%7Cdx)
i just get 1 split: original $\int _2^3$

so pretty much, how do you make those splits (for any problem for that matter); sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a split?

Comment: sorry for that I forgot how to word it; 

I had to split this integral $\int _{-2}^2\:\left|x^3+1\right|dx$ into $\int _{-2}^{-1}\:$ and $\int _{-1}^2\:$ to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your integral is done using just one of those three ranges is that the entire intevar of integration $[2,3]$ resides in the middle range $-1<x\leq 3$.

If your integral had been, say, 
$$
\int_{-2}^4 |x^2-2x-3|dx
$$
then you would need to break it into three integrals, as you had expected, because $[-2, 4]$ spills into all three of the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If the quantity inside the mod remains positive throughout the range of integraton, you can just remove the mod right? Just make the $(x-3)$ to $(3-x)$ here.